# Use sub-attribute of protobuf elements using word repeated described

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

for example,
I defined in proto buf as follow:

```
message small{
     low_id = 1;
     high_id = 2;
}
mesage middle{
     repeated small small_id = 1;
}
message big{
     middle middle_id = 1;
     int32 big_size = 2;
}
```

---

python file:

```
#init one example:
bigExample = big()
for i in range(1,10):
    smallExample = bigExample.middle_id.small_id.add()
    smallExample.low_id = i
    smallExample.high_id = i%2

#I want to re-sort the bigExample by high_id and low_id
#but using sorted(bigExample, key=bigExample.middle_id.small_id.high_id) will report error,
#AttributeError: 'RepeatedCompositeFieldContainer' object has no attribute 'high_id'
```

How should I do?

my problem:
1. cannot reference sub element of one repeated param
2. Anyway sort repeated instances by 2 param besides implement one sort method myself?

Comment: My problem 2: how to sort by 2 param 
now I got one way:
I can use lambda  in sorted:
sorted(example, key=lambda  x:x: (x[0], -x[1]))

Comment: Then the only problem is: 
How can I reference sub element of one repeated param
`bigExample.middle_id.small_id.high_id` seems not OK.

Answer (score 0):

I tried like following sectence, seems works well:

```
sorted(bigExample.middle_id , key=lambda x: (x.small_id.high_id, x.small_id.low_id ))
```